# How is the phrase “if not for…” used at the end of a sentence?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

> *His works were brilliant in their understandability -- if not their wordiness.*

How would you structure a sentence if you wanted to say, that *the understandability was brilliant but if you don't think that is, then the wordiness is.*

Would a comma be used after 'if not'?

Comment: Do you mean "if not *for* their wordiness"?  That would change the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: In this particular case, the phrase is being used synonymously with "notwithstanding": ignoring (for the moment) the fact that his works were wordy, their comprehensability, in-and-of itself, was brilliant. In other cases, particularly when combined with modal verbs / the subjunctive, it works like "except for": His works would be brilliant in their clarity, if not for their wordiness. @bcc32 *this is a comment by another user

Comment: Which makes the question rather unclear... what is the OP asking, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when you put an "if not for" phrase at the end of a sentence like that, you are showing a bit of sarcasm. Especially in the phrase you use above, the intent appears (to me) to be poking fun at the wordiness of his works.

But I'm gathering from your question that you want to leave it up to the reader to decide if they want to poke fun at the wordiness, if they don't agree that they're brilliant. I think I might phrase that this way:

> You may find his works to be brilliant in their understandability, but
>   if not, you can surely agree that they are lengthy!

Or, if you don't want to use second-person narrative, you could write:

> His works were considered brilliant in their understandability (although some found their wordiness to be the more shining aspect).

Also, you could simplify that whole sentence and say:

> His works were wordy but brilliant in their understandability.